# Use resources macro without :id in Phoenix Router

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

By default the `resources` macro appends an `/:id` at the end of the routes for actions on single resources.

However, I have a case where a user must always be logged in to perform actions on themselves. I prefer to get `:current_user` from `conn.assigns`, not by passing in/showing any parameter in the URL. I know that I can always write out the routes one by one. I just wonder if there is a way to let `resources` generate such paths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can do this by using the [`:singleton`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.4.0/Phoenix.Router.html#resources/4-singleton-resources) option:**

> When a resource needs to be looked up without referencing an ID, because it contains only a single entry in the given context, the `:singleton` option can be used to generate a set of routes that are specific to such single resource.

---

**Usage Example:**

```ex
resources "/user", UserController, singleton: true
```

This will generate the following routes:

> - GET /user
> - GET /user/new
> - POST /user
> - GET /user/edit
> - PATCH /user
> - PUT /user
> - DELETE /user

<sup>*You can combine it with the `:only` or `:except` options to include/exclude certain routes*</sup>